# Proc SQL Select Into not working as I would like

Tags: macros, proc-sql, select-into, macro-variable

One (I hope simple) question: why does the following code

```
DATA DIZIONARIO;
INFILE DATALINES DELIMITER=" ";
INPUT ENTRY $ TRADUZIONE $;
DATALINES;
0   K
1   5
2   L
3   9
4   G
5   3
6   Y
7   0
8   U
9   X
;
RUN;


%MACRO CODIFICA (VARIABILE);
PROC SQL /*NOPRINT*/;
    SELECT "IF SUBSTR(&VARIABILE., &I., 1)="!!"'"!!STRIP(ENTRY)!!"'"!!" THEN SUBSTR(&VARIABILE._CODIFICATO, &I., 1)="!!
        "'"!!STRIP(TRADUZIONE)!!"'"
    INTO :DIZIONARIO_&VARIABILE.
    SEPARATED BY " "
    FROM DIZIONARIO;
QUIT;
%MEND;
%CODIFICA(POLIZZE_QUADRO);
%CODIFICA(NUM_POLIZZA);
%CODIFICA(NRO_SINISTRO);

%PUT &=DIZIONARIO_POLIZZE_QUADRO. &=DIZIONARIO_NUM_POLIZZA. &=DIZIONARIO_NRO_SINISTRO.;
```

give back the following error message in the log? Also, it does not allow me to create the macro-variables DIZIONARIO_POLIZZE_QUADRO, DIZIONARIO_NUM_POLIZZA, and DIZIONARIO_NRO_SINISTRO that I would like to be able to re-call in a subsequent step of my code.

> 770  %CODIFICA(POLIZZE_QUADRO); WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I
> not resolved. WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I not resolved.
> NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
> real time           0.01 seconds
> cpu time            0.01 seconds
>
> 771  %CODIFICA(NUM_POLIZZA); WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I
> not resolved. WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I not resolved.
> NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
> real time           0.01 seconds
> cpu time            0.01 seconds
>
> 772  %CODIFICA(NRO_SINISTRO); WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I
> not resolved. WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I not resolved.
> NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
> real time           0.01 seconds
> cpu time            0.03 seconds
>
> WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference DIZIONARIO_POLIZZE_QUADRO not
> resolved. 773 774  %PUT &=DIZIONARIO_POLIZZE_QUADRO.
> &=DIZIONARIO_NUM_POLIZZA. &=DIZIONARIO_NRO_SINISTRO.; WARNING:
> Apparent symbolic reference DIZIONARIO_NUM_POLIZZA not resolved.
> WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference DIZIONARIO_NRO_SINISTRO not
> resolved. DIZIONARIO_POLIZZE_QUADRO. DIZIONARIO_NUM_POLIZZA.
> DIZIONARIO_NRO_SINISTRO.

Thanks in advance!